# Synch Kindle's bookmarks and notes

Tags: kindle, annotations, windows, android, synchronization

A few weeks ago I bought a book in Amazon and was using KindleForPC to read it. I was making notes and highlights and it was synching.

After reading some pages I downloaded Kindle for Android, and continued reading it from there. When I first opened in Android, my notes and highlights were available. As I read it I made new ones.

Now, weeks later, I opened it again in PC... old ones were still there, but the ones I made in Android aren't. I synched both softwares and they say they have latestfurthest read location. But notes and highlights aren't yet merged.

Aren't they shared at all? It would be a shame.

Answer (score 3):

[Kindle forum](http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG&cdThread=Tx240NVWZV6H7T6) gave me the solution! Synch only works when in the softwares's "home screen". Now they are properly synched :D sad I must always do it manually, they should automatically synch with Kindle server whenever there's internet available.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't work for me in that I've tried sync from the home screen without result.